# Overwrite file with last 4 lines using tail to make a log

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I'm trying to make a bash script that writes messages to a .plan file. I want to keep the file limited to five rows. So far I've tried to use the tail command in bash.

```
if [ $(cat .plan | wc -l) -eq 5 ]; then
    tail -n 4 .plan > .plan
fi
```

However, this just overwrites the file and enters one line instead of four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for checking the size up front...

```
$ tail -n5 .plan > temp && mv temp .plan
```

Comment: Great, this was elegant.

Answer (score 3):

So for not having to create a temporary file I found that this worked too

```
echo "$(tail -n 5 .plan)" > .plan
```